# A Perron-Frobenius problem

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, nonnegative-matrices

Let $A$ be an irreducible nonnegative matrix with column sums equal to 1.
Let $b\in R^n$ have components summing to 0, and let $u$ be the solution of $u=Au+b$ with components summing to 1 (unique under the above assumptions).
Let $X$ be the set of nonnegative vectors in $R^n$ whose components sum to 1. Can one always find a continuous Lyapunov function $L:X\to R_+$ (dependent on $A$) with the properties (i), (ii) below?

(i) $L(x)\le 0$ implies $x\le u$,

(ii) $x,y\in X$, $y\le Ax+b$ implies $L(y)\le \frac12 L(x)$.

I am interested in either a construction of $L$ given $A$, or an example $A$ together with a proof that $L$ doesn't exist for this particular $A$.

The motivation for my question is that under the assumptions made, Perron-Frobenius theory implies that any infinite sequence of $x^\ell\in X$ such that $x^{\ell+1}\le Ax^\ell+b$ for all $\ell$ necessarily converges to the set of $x$ with $x\le u$. The same would immediately be implied by the existence of the Lyapunov function.

Comment: how can a nonnegative vector be orthogonal to the all one vector? Isn't $X=\{0\}$?

Comment: @oferzeitouni: Sorry; I had simplified the problem too much. I corrected my question by making it inhomogeneous.

Comment: nonnegative components summing to zero???

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: Corrected; $b$ is unrestricted in sign.

Comment: u is not unique. Indeed you can add to any solution the P-F eigenvector.

Comment: @oferzeitouni: Corrected. I had forgotten the summing condition.